# Cannot Connect to Internet but can SSH into Solaris x86 (vs. 11)

Tags: networking, solaris

I am able to connect remotely to the machine using SSH, but I cannot ping `www.google.com` through the machine.

I did the following to make sure SSH was enabled (well I know it is, as I am using PuTTy):

```
# svcs ssh
STATE          STIME    FMRI
online          9:56:08 svc:/network/ssh:default
```

The machine name is:

```
# uname -a
SunOS solaris 5.11 11.1 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

And the precise version is:

```
# cat /etc/release
Oracle Solaris 11.1 X86
Copyright (c) 1983, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Assembled 19 September 2012
```

I am trying to install gcc, but it cannot contact valid package repository:

```
# pkg install gcc-45
pkg: 0/1 catalogs successfully updated:

Unable to contact valid package repository
Encountered the following error(s):
Unable to contact any configured publishers.
This is likely a network configuration problem.
Framework error: code: 6 reason: Couldn't resolve host 'pkg.oracle.com'
URL: 'http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release' (happened 4 times)
```

I don't understand that SSH can work, but my internet is not open.

This is what ifconfig -a returns:

```
# ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
net0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 10.0.11.17 netmask ff000000 broadcast 10.255.255.255
    ether 8:0:27:7:ad:7
lo0: flags=2002000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv6,VIRTUAL> mtu 8252 index 1
    inet6 ::1/128
net0: flags=20002004841<UP,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DHCP,IPv6> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe07:ad07/10
    ether 8:0:27:7:ad:7
```

net0 IPv4 is the correct IP address that I am using for SSH. The only way I could (possibly) get round it, is if I could edit the gateway and the DNS IP addresses.

Any help to get this machine to see the internet, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a name resolution problem. Can you ping a host on the Internet by IP address from the Solaris machine?

Comment: can you post this: svccfg -s network/dns/client listprop config

Comment: also this seems a Virtual Machine are sure you have the correct setting on the nic side?

Comment: @BitsOfNix `config/value_authorization astring     solaris.smf.value.name-service.dns.client`

Comment: @D_Bye I tried pinging www.google.com and got this response: `ping: getaddrinfo: temporary name resolution failure`
`ping: unknown host www.google.com`

Comment: @D_Bye suggested you ping an IP address, not a domain name, the idea is that you are connected to the internet but you have problems resolving domains to IPs. So, try `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: @terdon I now get this: `ping: sendto No route to host`

Comment: Are you on the same network as this machine? It looks like it simply does not have access to the internet, `ifconfig` only shows a local IP. If you connnect to the machine by name or by an IP starting with `10.`, you are probably on the same network.

Comment: Yeah, this machine (VM) is on the same network as my local machine (Win Vista). I have other VM's that are on the same network, but are different OS. Like I can't really use my Ubuntu machine to help me resolve a Solaris network issue ... Or can I?

Comment: OK, I have now refreshed the DNS Client: `svcadm refresh svc:/network/dns/client` and when I tried to ping `www.google.com`, it is saying: `ping: sendto No route to host`

Comment: @Kevdog777 - the "No route to host" message suggests that your Solaris VM doesn't have a default gateway configured. Do you have a file called `/etc/defaultrouter`? If so, does it contain the IP address of your network's gateway host?

Comment: @D_Bye Ah, it doesn't have the default Gateway. I know what the gateways are, but how should I add them? Like, what do I write in that file?

Comment: @Kevdog777 - That file simply contains the LAN IP address of the gateway host. You might need to run `route add default 10.0.11.1` (assuming that's the gateway IP address) to activate the change now. Putting it in the config file will mean it gets picked up next time the machine starts up.

Comment: Spot on @D_Bye! Thank you so much for your help on this.

Comment: @D_Bye just a quick question. Where is the config file? Just so I won't have to redo this again the next time I start it up.

Comment: @Kevdog777 - I've gathered the salient points from these comments into an answer. Should see you right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `couldn't resolve host` in the output to the `pkg` command suggests some fundamental misconfiguration of the network stack on the Solaris box. Given that you can connect to it over ssh from another machine on the LAN, we know its networking stack is initialised, and that it is passing packets correctly. The problem is therefore most likely to be due to a name resolution failure, or a missing gateway specification.

The simplest way to find out which problem is causing your lack of service, is just to try to ping a machine on the Internet by its IP address. A successful response means that routing is fine, and we then need to look at the name resolution settings on the box. If the ping fails, however, it should give you a reason why.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: sendto No route to host
```

In this case, as you reported above in the comments, `ping` fails with a message that the network stack couldn't find a route to the remote host. On Solaris, there should be a file, `/etc/defaultrouter`, which contains the LAN IP address of your gateway machine. If that file doesn't exist, or contains the wrong IP address, that is the cause of your problem. Fix the file, and run `route add default 10.0.11.1` to install the new default route in the IP stack now.

When it boots, the system will automatically configure a default gateway based on the contents of `/etc/defaultrouter` - there should be no need to run the `route add` again manually.

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is true to the spirit of Solaris 11  (as opposed to Solaris 10). Isn't fiddling with `/etc/defaultrouter` file the old way of doing things?   I would simply do `route -p add default 10.0.11.1`. Again I'm struggling to learn the new ways myself so this is more of a question than something I'm sure of.